# how much is it right to create JAXBContext using newInstance() with each method call?

Tags: java, jaxb

In spring boot project I create JAXBContext bean:

```
@Configuration
public class MarshallerConfig {

    @Bean
    JAXBContext jaxbContext() throws JAXBException {
        return JAXBContext.newInstance(my packages);
    }
}
```

And I create Wrapper for use this context:

```
@Component
public class MarshallerImpl implements Marshaler {

    private final JAXBContext jaxbContext;

    public MarshallerImpl(JAXBContext jaxbContext) {
        this.jaxbContext = jaxbContext;
    }

     //murshall and unmarshal methosds imlementation
    }
```

When I create `JAXBContext` like bean - I know that this `JAXBContext` will be singleton. But Now I need implement marhall method for marshall element without `@XMLRootElement` annotation. I Implement it like in this [article](https://www.codenotfound.com/jaxb-marshal-element-missing-xmlrootelement-annotation.html)

```
@Override
public <T> String marshalToStringWithoutRoot(T value, Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        // format the XML output
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, false);

        QName qName = new QName(value.getClass().getPackage().toString(), value.getClass().getSimpleName());
        JAXBElement<T> root = new JAXBElement<>(qName, clazz, value);

        marshaller.marshal(root, stringWriter);

        return stringWriter.toString();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I create `JAXBContext` into method `JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);`.

**How correct is it? every time create an object using `newInstance`?**

I looked a little inside this method and did not see that it was a singleton.

Comment: Don't do it. Have a look at [How can I improve JAXB performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607318/how-can-i-improve-jaxb-performance)

Comment: @ThomasFritsch Yes. I ask about it. But then I have a problem. how do i convert an object without `@XMLRootElement` annotation?

Comment: You can also try to reuse the `JAXBContext`s in that case. May be by caching them in a `static Map<Class, JAXBContext>`.

Answer (score 0):

Because creating a `JAXBContext` is very time-consuming,
you should avoid it as much as possible.

You can achieve this by caching them in a `Map<Class<?>, JAXBContext>`.

```
private static Map<Class<?>, JAXBContext> contextsByRootClass = new HashMap<>();

private static JAXBContext getJAXBContextForRoot(Class<?> clazz) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext context = contextsByRootClass.get(clazz);
    if (context == null) {
        context = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
        contextsByRootClass.put(clazz, context);
    }
    return context;
}
```

Finally, in your `marshalToStringWithoutRoot` method you can replace

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
```

by

```
JAXBContext jc = getJAXBContextForRoot(clazz);
```